# Using WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this simple equation with a event:

```
   sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == 0, v[t] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Evaluate[t == 2], {v[t] -> -v[t]}]}, {x[t], v[t]}, {t, 0,
    10}]
   Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 4}]
```

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Open up the documentation and read about `NDSolve`

Comment: Can you give me a more specific answer. I guess it has to be something with using the highest order derivative inside the whenevent?

Comment: After executing your code there are a bunch of error messages. Did you try to go after those ?

Comment: `v[t] == 2` does not make sense because it never happens. Lets say `t==2` would be helpful, but I get this error: `Unable to reinitialize the system at t = 2. within specified \
tolerances.`

Comment: @sektor Those errors are caused by DSolve not given a solution, i.e., the plot causes the messages, not the DSolve itself. It is *that* what needs to be solved. In principle WhenEvent should work for DSolve too, not only NDSolve.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Copy-pasting just the `sol` part throws a bunch of messages for me, dunno 'bout you.

Comment: @sektor No messages, just the input returned as given

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm using v.9.0.0.1 as I don't want to pollute my v10 workspace :D

Comment: @sektor OK, makes sense. WhenEvent has been updated to work with more functions than NDSolve in V10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the option `DiscreteVariables` which tells `NDSolve` which of the variables have to be understood as discrete variables, that is variables which only change due to `WhenEvents` (see the documentation for `DiscreteVariables` for details). For those, you have to provide an initial condition (`v[0]==1.`) but no differential equation. The following code will do what I think you want:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == v[t],
    x[0] == 0,
    v[0] == 1,
    WhenEvent[t == 2, v[t] -> -v[t]]
  },
  {x[t], v[t]},
  {t, 0, 10},
  DiscreteVariables -> {v}
]

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exacly what I was missing!